# Safari Don't Receive Web Push Notification

Tags: safari, web-push

I have created a website that is enabled to receive push notifications when this is viewed with browsers such as Safari.
Unfortunately I noticed that despite the registration being successful, also obtaining the browser Device token, once the push notification is sent to the Apple server, this replies to me saying that it has been taken over, but then it is not received by the computer enabled to receive .
I did everything, I also tried to generate the digital certificate because I thought that was the problem but in reality, despite having created it correctly, I do not receive notifications.
Is there anything I can look specifically at?
Thanks,
Vincenzo